# Getting stuck when solving second order non-homogeneous linear differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm trying to solve: $y'' + 10y' + 25y = (3x+2)e^{-5x}$

I start by rewriting as $(D^2 + 10D + 25)y = (3x + 2)e^{-5x}$

We have a non-distinct real root of multiplicity 2 which is -5.

The homogeneous solution is then $y_{h} = (C_{1} + C_{2})e^{-5x}$

We now find the candidate for the undermined coefficients method.

$F(x) = (3x+2)e^{-5x}$

$F'(x) = (-5Ax + A - 5B)e^{-5x}$

$F''(x) = (25Ax - 10A + 25B)e^{-5x}$

$(3x+2)$ is in the form of a first-degree polynomial and $e^{-5x}$ is an exponential function.

So our particular solution is $y_{p} = (Ax + B)e^{-5x}$ (Should the exponential be multiplied by C?)

My problem is that when I replace $y_{p}$ into the differential equation of line 1, I get 0, so I can't continue the problem...

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. What is the differentiation you have conducted for $y_\mathrm{p}$? Notice that it is a product

Comment: @kangzhe I edited my post with the derivatives I did. I assume they are not correct? I'm doing it with a scientific calculator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your root $-5$ is double, the right form of $y_p$ is
$$
Y_p=x^2(ax+b)e^{-5x}.
$$

Comment: Hi, I was able to find the solution with your post. Thank you ! But I don't understand where the x^2 is coming from, why does root -5 being double mean we need x^2 in front ?

Comment: There are rules concerning the form of the particular solution for different forms of the right hand side. If the right hand side is $P_n(x)e^{ax}$ where P is a polynomial of degree n and $a$ is a real root of multiplicity $k$ then there exists a unique solution of the form $y_p(x)=x^kQ_n(x)e^{ax}$ where $Q_n$ is a polynomial of degree $n$.

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**

Here it is another way to approach such ODE.

I would start with noticing that

\begin{align*}
y'' + 10y' + 25 = (3x+2)e^{-5x} \Longleftrightarrow (ye^{5x})'' = 3x+2
\end{align*}

Can you take it from here?

**EDIT**

According to the integrating factor method, we deduce that

\begin{align*}
y'' + 10y' + 25 = (3x+2)e^{-5x} & \Longleftrightarrow (y' + 5y)' + 5(y' + 5) = (3x+2)e^{-5x}\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow u' + 5u = (3x+2)e^{-5x}\\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow u'e^{5x} + 5ue^{5x} = 3x + 2\\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow (ue^{5x})' = 3x + 2\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow (y'e^{5x} + 5ye^{5x})' = 3x+2\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow (ye^{5x})'' = 3x + 2
\end{align*}

where $u = y' + 5y$.

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your comment... I will try to solve the problem with the hint you've given me. But for the first derivative of (y * e^(5x)) should I do a chain rule as the first step ?

Comment: You can integrate both sides twice and multiply the result by $e^{-5x}$ afterwards.

Comment: I see ! But how did you first notice that the original equation can be written in this simplified way ?

Comment: I will edit my answer in order to provide the full explanation. Please let me know if you still have any questions.